# Probability of certain outcomes after moving a randomly chosen ball from bag A to bag B, and in the opposite direction

Tags: probability

Bag A contains 6 yellow balls and 8 blue balls while bag B contains 5 yellow balls and 9 blue balls. A ball is picked from bag A and placed into bag B and then a ball is picked from bag B and returned to bag A. Calculate the probability that after two draws:

a)  Bag A contains 7 yellow and 7 blue balls

b)  Bag B contains 6 yellow and 8 blue balls

c)  Bag A contains 6 yellow and 8 blue balls

d)  Bag B contains 5 yellow and 10 blue balls

---

After two draws 4 final configurations are possible:

[A(6Y,8B) B(7Y,7B)]  [A(8Y,6B) B(5Y,9B)] [A(7Y,7B) B(6Y, 8B)] [A(7Y,7B) B(6Y, 8B)]

I can easily figure out the d) part. It should be 0 as it doesn't appear in any of the final 4 configurations. But how do I compute the other parts of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is best described with a tree diagram.  I have used color brown in place of yellow to improve visibility.

[image: Tree diagram]

This diagram shows the two decisions being made and the two possibilities for each decision along with the probability of making each decision and the results of each decision.

To arrive at a particular leaf of the tree (final state) corresponds to traveling along each branch to get there, which has probability of arriving at the leaf equal to the multiplication of the probabilities along each branch along the path.  For example, to arrive at the top leaf occurs with probability $\frac{6}{14}\cdot\frac{6}{15} = \frac{6}{35}$.  To calculate the probabilities on the branches, it is simply the number of the specific color balls in the bag from which you are grabbing divided by the total number of balls in the bag from which you are grabbing.

From having made this diagram, one can see what the probabilities of each outcome are.  Note: The top leaf and bottom leaf have the same outcome, so you could add the probabilities for these together and draw it as a single leaf.

Comment: Many thanks for explaining this so clearly!